# Hosting a Win32 window in a WPF floating tear off tab

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I am currently hosting a Win32 OSG (built on OpenGL) control in WPF. I am using the telerik docking library. Everything works fine when a pane is docked with the MainWindow. However, when I tear off the tab, **the OSG graphics are not recreated in the tear off tab**.

I am subclassing `HwndHost` which uses `CreateWindowEx` to create a native Win32 host and returns the native handle (see code below). I then pass that handle to the native OSG code which is being hosted by a user control.

```
    // inside my ControlHost class which derives from HwndHost
    protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
    {
        hwndControl = IntPtr.Zero;
        hwndHost = IntPtr.Zero;

        hwndHost = CreateWindowEx(0, "MDIClient", "",
                                  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                                  0, 0,
                                  hostHeight, hostWidth,
                                  hwndParent.Handle,
                                  (IntPtr)HOST_ID,
                                  IntPtr.Zero,
                                  0);
        return new HandleRef(this, hwndHost);
    }
```

When debugging into the above method, as expected, the `hwndParent.handle` parameter is the handle of the WPF MainWindow when the tab is docked in the Main window. However, when I pull the tab out and it becomes a floating tab, the `hwndParent.handle` attribute is a value that I cannot find with Spy++. The floating tab 'hwnd` value according to Spy++ is the same as that produced by the above method. I suspect this may be the reason why the OSG graphics are not displaying.

My questions are:

1. I know natively with WPF there is only a HWND associated with each Window object, however how does this work with floating panels in docking libraries? Are the floating panels actually a window as the underlying object or a usercontrol?
2. Any ideas why my native OSG graphics are not being displayed on the floating tear off tab? Is it related to the parent handle that is being passed in?

Comment: Can you please share the example code how you integrated Win32 with WPF ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RadDocking control uses transparent WPF windows to display its ToolWindows by default and as a platform limitation of WPF, you cannot display any non-WPF content in such transparent windows. What you could do is to make the windows non-transparent by setting the RadWindowInteropHelper.AllowTransparency attached property of ToolWindow to False. This could be achieved using a custom GeneratedItemsFactory. Please refer to [this forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/docking/hosting-a-win32-window-in-a-wpf-floating-tear-off-tab.aspx) for as sample project.

Regards,
Miroslav Nedyalkov,
Telerik team.

Comment: I am displaying non-WPF content when the pane is docked it is only when the pane is not docked and floating that it doesn't work. Does that mean the window is only transparent when it is floating?

Comment: Ok. That actually worked just adding the NonTrasparentWindowsGeneratedItemsFactory as per your sample project. Thanks!